# Scrolling For Div on Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have one div in this i has  tables ,which have fixed height and width.
Every click is displaying  another table.
When Clcik on particular cell , which is bottom of the page..then ,i need to scroll the scrollbar automotically , window height should not be increase and should not be create extra space on the page.

```
    <div id="panel" style="width: 1354px; height: 565px;">
    <div id="body">
    <table></table>
    </div>
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please post your current HTML and JQuery code

Comment: Please Provide code which is used to scroll the scrollbar of a div automotically...

Comment: If your div has a scroll bar, then you could simply set the scrollTop for your div and the scroll should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code for scroll :

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: This is solved my problem ..thanks for all      $("$divId").scrollTop(RangeToScroll);

Comment: You Mean  $("#divId").scrollTop(RangeToScroll);